# Extract key names to a list

Tags: ansible

Given the following, I would like to end up with a list of usernames matching those UIDs, e.g. users: [ 'u1' ]

```
- name: getent
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: getent
      getent:
        database: passwd
        key: "{{ item }}"
        split: ':'
      with_items:
        - 20001
      register: users
    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ users.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.getent_passwd') | list }}"


TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "users": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "_ansible_parsed": true,
                "ansible_facts": {
                    "getent_passwd": {
                        "u1": [ <-- I do not care about anything contained within u1!
```

As far as above I end up with

```
[{u'u1': [u'x', u'20001', u'20001', u'', u'/home/u1', u'/sbin/nologin']}]
```

How can I get

```
['u1']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/) query:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ users.results | json_query('[].ansible_facts.getent_passwd.keys(@)[]') }}"
```

- `[].ansible_facts.getent_passwd` is equivalent to your filter
- `keys(@)` function returns the key names for the above list
- `[]` flattens the resulting list